# Output of a switch case based code snippet in which the block with matching case have no code statements

Tags: c, switch-statement

The following code snippet having switch case has become difficult for me to solve. I need the solution.

```
int main(){
int i, j, x=0;
for(i=1;i<5;++i)
    for(j=0;j<i;++j){
        switch(i+j-1){
            case -1:
            case 0:
            x+=1;
            break;
            case 1:
            case 2:
            case 3:
            x+=2;
            default:
            x+=3;

        }
        printf("%d",x);

        }

   printf("\nx=%d",x);
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried it yourself, and compared it to the actual result?

Comment: "*I need the solution.*" is the worst kind of "question" I could think of. Your title suggest you want to know the output? well, then just run it?

Comment: The flow will reach the next `case` statemet until a `break` is found

Comment: In case you don't know: `case` is just the *entry point* a `switch` jumps to. Without a `break`, you don't jump out of the block.

Comment: I have run this code snippet and I had solved myself as well. But I got confused with those cases which have no statements inside.

Answer (score 0):

The second for-loop (which also nests the switch statement) can't be executed because `i<j` is always false. The main function will therefore only print `x=0` three times.

Answer (score 0):

Without actually knowing what the code should do one problem i see it the

```
for(j=0;i<j;++j)
```

should probably be

```
for(j=0;j<i;++j)
```